# Showing that a linear transformation doesn't exist

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors, linear-transformations

Let $ f\colon\Bbb R^{3} \longrightarrow\Bbb R^{2} $ be a linear transformation such that

$$\left\{\begin{array}{l}f(1,2,1)=(2,3)\\f(0,1,1) = (1,2)\\f(1,0,-1) = (2,2)\end{array}\right.$$

I have to determine if such a transformation exist. I have shown that $(1,2,1), (0,1,1), (1,0,-1)$ are linearly dependent so they can't be a basis of $\Bbb R^{3}$. Is that enough to prove it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $(1,2,1)$, $(0,1,1)$, and $(1,0,−1)$ are linearly dependent, there has to be some non-trivial linear relation between them. One such relation is that$$(1,2,1)=2(0,1,1)+(1,0,-1).$$But $(2,3)\ne2(1,2)+(2,2)$. That is, $f(1,2,1)\ne2f(0,1,1)+f(1,0,-1)$. Therefore, there is no such linear map.

Answer (score 0):

Note the relationship consisting only of the summation of scaled inputs: first input minus double the second input yields the third input. If the transform is linear, by definition, the outputs would have to be related in the same way. It is sufficient to prove the function is non-linear by showing this relationship does not hold for the outputs.